# Update row in TABLE1 using value from another row in TABLE1 to lookup value in TABLE2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table as follows

TABLE1

```
Id   UserId  Type       Value
1    AAA     companyid  123
2    AAA     branchid   
3    BBB     companyid  124
4    BBB     branchid   
5    CCC     companyid  125
6    CCC     branchid
```

and TABLE2

```
BranchId   CompanyId   Name
1          123         RedBranch
2          123         YellowBranch
3          123         GreenBranch
4          124         SouthBranch
5          125         NorthBranch
```

I need to update Type in TABLE1 WHERE Type = 'branchid' using the value in Type = 'companyid' for the same UserId.  Once I have the correct 'companyid' I want to use the following SELECT to get the TOP BranchId from TABLE2

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id 
FROM TABLE2
WHERE CompanyId = (correct companyid from TABLE1)
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

How can I achieve this in one Update statement?

Comment: Do you mean you effectively want to fill in the blank Values in Table 1 using Table 2?

Comment: Well yes but taking the TOP corresponding id from TABLE2.  So for CompanyId 123 I would want branchid in TABLE1 for User BBB to be 3

Comment: For CompanyID = 123 there are 3 branches (red, yellow and green). Which one should be chosen to update branch from TABLE1?

Comment: Edited last comment to explain.  It should be 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a stab at it:

```
update T1
set Value = (select max(BranchId) from Table2 where CompanyId = T1a.value)
from Table1 T1
inner join Table1 T1a on T1a.UserId = T1.UserId and T1a.Type = 'companyid'
where T1.Type = 'branchid'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand the quesion, but maybe...

```
with maxBranch as
(
select
     max(BranchId) as BranchId
    ,CompanyId
from TABLE2
group by CompanyId
)
update t1
set t1.Value = m.BranchID
from TABLE1 as t1
join TABLE1 as t11
    on t1.UserId = t11.UserId
    and t1.Type = 'branchid'
    and t11.Type = 'companyid' 
join maxBranch as m
    on m.CompanyId = t11.Value
```